# Couchbase document expiration performance

Tags: couchbase

I have a 6 nodes couchbase cluster with about 200 million documents in one bucket. I need to delete about 100 million documents within that bucket. I'm planning to have a view that gives me an index of the documents I need to delete and then do a touch operation to set the expiry of those documents to the next day. 
I understand that couchbase will run a background expiry pager operation on regular intervals to delete the documents. Will this expiry pager process on 100 million documents have an impact on couchbase cluster performance?

Answer (score 2):

If you set them to expire all around the same time, maybe. It depends on your cluster's sizing if it will effect performance. If it were me, unless you have some compelling reason to get rid of them all right this moment, I would play it safe just set a random TTL for a time between now and a few days from now. Then the server will take care of it for you and you do not have to worry about this.

[Document expiration](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.0/#about-document-expiration) in Couchbase is in seconds or UNIX epoc time. If over 30 days, it has to be UNIX epoc time.

Comment: However you end up doing it in code, please write up a blog post somewhere and link it back to this question. I am sure others would be interested in knowing how you solved it in your view and code.